# Aumentar tamanho do GestureDetector Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, tenho um `GestureDetector`que recebe como filho um container com `width: 20` e `heigth: 20` e com isso meu GestureDetector fica apenas 20x20, como mostra a imagem (o tamanho é só a bolinha cinza)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok, preciso aumentar a area do `GestureDetector` pensei em passar um Container como filho e deixar cor transparente, e como filho do container a minha "bolinha cinza (que é um container também)", mas não deu certo, ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, preciso de uma maneira pra aumentar apenas o local clicavel e não o container da bolinha cinza, como posso fazer? meu código está abaixo

```
GestureDetector(
                  child: Online(
                      online: lista[index].online, width: 20, heigth: 20),
                  onTap: () {
                    _alterarStatusFun(lista[index]);
                  }),
```

O online eu criei como classe pois uso em outros lugares :

```
class Online extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool online;
  final double width;
  final double heigth;
  const Online({Key key, this.online, this.width, this.heigth})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return online
        ? Container(
            width: width,
            height: heigth,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 255, 0, 1),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            width: width,
            height: heigth,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Englobe o widget `Online` em um padding com o valor da "margem clicável" que você deseja:

```
double margemClicavel = 50.0;
GestureDetector(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(margemClicavel),
                    child: Online(
                      online: lista[index].online, width: 20, heigth: 20),
                      onTap: () {
                        _alterarStatusFun(lista[index]);
                  })),
```

Isso irá fazer o GestureDetector envolver não apenas o container, como todo o padding em torno dele.
Porém, como o `Padding` não desenha nada na tela, o seguinte comportamento, que é descrito na documentação, irá ocorrer:

> By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches; this behavior can be controlled with behavior.

Tradução livre: Caso o `child` seja invisível ele terá os cliques ignorados. Esse comportamento pode ser modificado pela property `behavior`.

Portanto, para corrigir isso, use nesta property o valor `HitTestBehavior.opaque`:

```
double margemClicavel = 50.0;
GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(margemClicavel),
                    child: Online(
                      online: lista[index].online, width: 20, heigth: 20),
                      onTap: () {
                        _alterarStatusFun(lista[index]);
                  })),
```

O valor dos valores do enum `HitTestBehavior` podem ser conferidos na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html).

Comment: Bacana, funcionou bem, obrigado pela ajuda